# Does JavaScript store reference to every element in array of ints?

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory-management, int

In C\C++, Java, C# code like this

```
arr = new int[5];
```

will be stored in memory using `5 * 4 = 40` bytes, since every `int` just a 32 bits number.

Is it true for JavaScript? Or does it store ints as references to the objects that contain boxed ints?

Comment: JS always uses values, not references. With that said, what the array will be stored as depends on the implementation and the optimisations chosen for your code. If you *only* have integers, then implementations can optimise that as an array of ints. However, if you put in mixed data, the environment might choose to expand that array to take up more memory anticipating you might put, say, strings in it.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you! One more question: where I can read about your answer in more details? Since it's very interesting if, say, V8 can use native array of ints.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I've read bits and pieces around the web for what engine optimisations are done. I don't think I can point you to a single place.